# What plants is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, tropical, dracaena

I recently got this plant and I looked up on internet but couldn't find one. I don't know anything about this plant and so my question. What plant is this? Corn Plant or Janet Craig or none?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is better to have a question (a identification) per *question*.

Comment: Agree.  This question will likely be closed shortly.

Comment: Not sure about this one - leaves don't look floppy enough to be Janet Craig...

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because it's been edited to ask about just one plant. Although someone might know right away, more details would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue What kind of more info I am supposed to give?

Comment: Hi! What I meant was things like where you live; is the plant inside or out; what kind of light conditions; its age; if it's grown any flowers, etc. Also a more detailed title. The description of the [identification tag](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) gives a good explanation of what to include in order to get the best answers. Also check out the other questions tagged [tag:identification]. These details can help keep the question from being closed as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: I just got this plant, some 3-4 days ago, and I don't know anything about it. I just want this plant identified. I live in Delhi, and I don't know if it had or will bear any flowers. I cannot tell about the age. :( @Sue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the question on another garden forum, and they told me it's Dracaena Reflexa. After some google search, I found it to be [Pleomele - Dracaena Reflexa](http://lee.ifas.ufl.edu/Hort/GardenPubsAZ/Dracaena_Reflexa_Fact_Sheet.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Could be a young Janet Craig, but also looks like a leggy Green Jewel to me (its more compact). All fall under Dracaena anyway, so if you Google image search Dracaena, I'm sure you'll find a match rather quickly. All have similar care requirements; moderate exposure, moderate moisture. Too much water is quickly displayed by yellowing tips. Very hardy and one of my favorite houseplants due to the fact.

Edit: This site may help you pin down what you have. It actually looks like the Elegance Cane they have pictured:
[MiamiTropicalPlants.com](http://www.miamitropicalplants.com/product-category/tropical-foliage-by-miami-tropical-plants/dracaena/)

This site also:
[PlantTruck.com](http://www.planttruckcart.com/available.jsp)

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question.  Your answer says "go look here".  If you can provide more points about why it is a dracaena then this would be a better answer.

Comment: I actually suggested a couple possible cultivars, then directed him to a resource that may be able to help. It is definitely a dracaena of some sort, just not positive of the cultivar without closer observation. If it were on of the variegated varieties it would probably be a bit easier to identify. Sorry but I can't do much better without more pics or info (size, age, origin, etc).

Comment: @elCrash Added more pics. I couldn't find one on the sites mentioned.