# Tiny Yellow spots on Dracaena Reflexa Pleomele. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, dracaena

It's not on all leaves, but, let's say, on 70% of the leaves.

Well-drained soil. Medium-bright indirect light. I water it every two days, ~250ml water. It was fine a few days back, but now the leaves are getting these yellow spots. Here are they:

[image]

This is the plant I am talking about.

[What plants is this?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/what-plants-is-this)

Close-up underside pic of the affected leaf:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely to be your watering regime.  You have an old established plant with a good root system.  You are wetting the top of the soil too often and keeping the rest of the root ball dry.

- Water every 7 to 14 days with a litre of water.
- The top few centimeters of soil should be dry before you water
- ideally some water should come out of the bottom of the pot after watering

Spotting can be a sign of spider mites but there are none to be seen on the underside of the leaf and dracaena's have a waxy leaf which reduces mites. [This question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9002/what-could-cause-brown-spots-on-the-leaves-of-a-song-of-india-plant-dracaena-re) shows what poor watering habits can do with reflexas; they encourage one or all of virus/fungus/bacteria.

Confirmation would be if it started in the older leaves.

Comment: This looks as if some sucking insect has an effect.  I've not seen this on overly watered plants.  Your answer for watering is great, but why these spots from over watering?  You know I am very interested as I respectomundo your knowledge!!

Comment: Yes, it started on old leaves too. I haven't watered them till yesterday. The top layer is very dry. Should I water them now? if yes, 1 litre?

Comment: @4-K you have to use your judgement.. you are on site..I would wait a few days

Comment: I haven't watered it till now. The yellow spots are still there. Some bottom leaves are drooping. What should I do?

Comment: the yellow spots will not go away unfortunately as they are damage to the leaf tissue.  If the bottom leaves are drooping give it a good water and let drain

Comment: @kevinsky Thanks! I thought the spots would go away once the plants gets fine.

Comment: @kevinsky The spots are getting bigger and appearing more. I watered the plant on 16th July. Haven't watered it till now. I poured at least 500ml, and it all drained well.

Comment: take it out of the pot and look at the roots, should be firm and yellow or white, not soft and black indicating root rot

Comment: @kevinsky Now that we know the condition of the roots, are you sure it is definitely caused by the sand(too much water holding)? The spots are spreading and getting bigger.

Comment: Once a virus/fungus/bacteria is established the only way to stop it is to change the underlying causes and let the plant outgrow it.  So repot the plant and move to higher light and water less.