# Are these roots healthy or bad?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, roots, dracaena

Related: [Tiny Yellow spots on Dracaena Reflexa Pleomele. What I am doing wrong?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/27172/tiny-yellow-spots-on-dracaena-refelxa-pleomele-what-i-am-doing-wrong)

I am having trouble taking this plant out to examine the roots. I have used some technique to take it out but it is not helping much. I watered it with at least a litre of water and let it be for 30 minutes so the soil softens up. The water quickly drained and the soil is now completely wet. When I tried to scrape the soil from the edges, the roots were damaged while scraping. The roots are all red and hollow and very soft. When I broke it, I found a very thin white root(or whatever.) Here is the pic(can upload more pics if required):

[image]

Comment: Small roots *are* soft. Bigger ones get tough. Are they soft to the point of being soggy and waek? What size are we looking at here? Some roots are naturally reddish.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I took the big red one, broke it, and found it was hollow with a very thin thread like root. I will try a pic tomorrow.