# Finally got the rootball out, please diagnose the roots and health of this plant

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, roots, repotting, root-pruning

Related question: [Are these roots healthy or bad?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/27556/are-these-roots-healthy-or-bad)

[My Dracaena Reflexa Pleomele started having tiny yellow spots for some weeks](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/27172/tiny-yellow-spots-on-dracaena-reflexa-pleomele-what-i-am-doing-wrong). As a result, I was asked to take the rootball and inspect it. I took out the rootball, and here  it is(since I don't know much about roots and plants):

[image]
[image]
[image]

You see the fat root in the third pic? I broke it, The root was hard, but not stiff. When I squeezed it, water came out bubbling. The root smelled like peanut, so I think the root is healthy.

However, the small ones just dropped when I gave a nice light rubbing. They are hollow and dried out. The small roots are dead? Here is the pic:
[image]

Should I let the plant rest in the soil it has been resting? If not, what should I do? just get rid of the soil and plant it in another soil? 
If yes, is this soil suitable for this plant?

[image]

Comment: Those pix could serve as a definition for the term rootbound.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Are the roots healthy?

Comment: Look it. Just too many of them. I'd answer, but have never up-potted a Dracena. The process probably involves root spreading and such, but am not sure. Someone more knowledgeable will likely be along soon.

Comment: Is there any soil in there at all ? I would wait for proper advice, but suspect a root prune and repotting with good soil may be in the answer somewhere. How long has it been in the current pot?

Comment: good luck muscling the roots apart to replant IN THE GROUND!!!!!!!

Comment: No problemo 4-k...a knife is fine, I just RIP these roots apart, quite a bit, or take a knife and cut first then FRUFF up these roots (trust me they will LOVE the help) and then repot in a slightly larger pot with potting soil.  Any time I repot any plant I break up the root ball slightly before replanting.  This is a POTTED plant not a garden plant, unless you live in the tropics...commercially when we plant plants from the nursery we take a shovel and hack the root balls 2 or 3 times...root bound or not.  New roots are then encouraged and they won't be circling anymore to really do damage.

Comment: @JonathanC I cannot say. I got this plant one month back from a nursery and didn't ask them the age of the plant.

Comment: @stormy Thanks! Sadly, I don't have the proper knife to cut the rootball. Should I remove all the dead and hollow roots(the ones at the top)?

Comment: Nope and there is no proper knife necessary!  Remember, I had my guys using shovels to split open all potted roots and they were not the most delicate of people!!  I usually get my fingers and quickly pry apart, bust apart those roots before planting.  This is NOT like rocket science (whatever THAT is)...this means getting your hands in dirt, roots, dirty fingernails...and enjoying the process of reconnecting with this natural world!!  There are different types of roots...some are just support for the feeders, others for support of the plant's weight, and there are the fine feeder roots...

Comment: And have you every 'butterflied' steak, roasts, turkeys?  Using the same idea one can butterfly open, chop off chunks to help it fit into the plant's new home.  Not at all saying this is necessary but you will need a bigger pot...not too much bigger, perhaps 2 or 3 inches larger.  Root balls are not delicate items...

Comment: I gotta figure out how to start drawing to explain stuff and easily post it...later, alligator.

Comment: @stormy Thanks! I will use my hands too. And looking forward to the pics, if yo can manage :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plant is pot bound but that should not be the cause of the spotting.  Nonetheless repotting is a good idea:

- get a sharp knife and some interior plant potting soil. Something with extra drainage factors like perlite or vermiculite.  Do not use soil from the garden which will not drain as readily in a pot.
- remove the plant from the pot. Check that the drainage hole is not plugged
- using the knife remove one quarter to one third from the bottom of the root ball in a flat slice
- make several vertical slashes approximately one inch deep around the circumference of the pot. Remove the ends of roots that have been cut
- add new potting soil to the bottom
- return the plant to the pot, pack some more soil in, water thoroughly

There are a lot of dead roots including the hollow ones in the pictures. That is why repotting is a good idea.  The picture of the soil you show is not suitable for indoor plants.  Consider adding perlite or vermiculite to improve drainage.

Comment: So what is the cause of the spotting? And the roots are normal or bad? I mean the hollow ones.